# Trim a part of a String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a column which is long. I need to take only the name from the column.

This is the column name:

```
QSTY-IOM-HFVNBJGYG | Mobile #: 9876541323 | CUSTOMER NAME: MNOP UNIPOUYTREA POIUY | INVOICE DATE:02/28/18 | EMP#: 101466 | EMPLOYEE NAME: ANGELINA CASIANO
```

I just need to pick up the customer name from this column. I tried Charindex and it was displying an error message of

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

output:

```
MNOP UNIPOUYTREA POIUY
```

Comment: "I tried Charindex" may we see that attempt? It is probably the correct way.

Comment: select substring
 (Description,
  charindex('|',Description,1)+1,
  charindex(' ',Description,1)-charindex('|',Description,1)
  ),* from #Final

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use it's built in [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) method to convert your string to a table.
Then all you have to do is to select the value from the table that starts with `CUSTOMER NAME:`, like this:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(300) = 'QSTY-IOM-HFVNBJGYG | Mobile #: 9876541323 | CUSTOMER NAME: MNOP UNIPOUYTREA POIUY | INVOICE DATE:02/28/18 | EMP#: 101466 | EMPLOYEE NAME: ANGELINA CASIANO'

SELECT [value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s, '|')
WHERE LTRIM([value]) LIKE 'CUSTOMER NAME:%'
```

However, you should read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and normalize your database if possible.

Answer (score 3):

With SQL-Serer-2016+ you should use `STRING_SPLIT`.

With lower versions I'd use this approach:

A quite straight forward combination of `XQuery` and `T-SQL`

```sql
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000)='QSTY-IOM-HFVNBJGYG | Mobile #: 9876541323 | CUSTOMER NAME: MNOP UNIPOUYTREA POIUY | INVOICE DATE:02/28/18 | EMP#: 101466 | EMPLOYEE NAME: ANGELINA CASIANO';

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @string AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' | ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
          .query('/x[substring(text()[1],1,13)="CUSTOMER NAME"]')
          .value('(/x/text())[1]','varchar(1000)') AS TheFragment
)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(TheFragment,CHARINDEX(':',TheFragment)+2,1000)))
FROM Casted;
```

The `CTE` will transform your string to an XML, which allows to read each part separately. The `.query()` will return the one fragment starting with `"CUSTOMER NAME"` while `.value()` takes the (complete) text out of this fragment. The rest is easy `SUBSTRING`...

Answer (score 2):

If the format is consistent, you can try like below:

```
declare @val varchar(max) = 'QSTY-IOM-HFVNBJGYG | Mobile #: 9876541323 | CUSTOMER NAME: MNOP UNIPOUYTREA POIUY | INVOICE DATE:02/28/18 | EMP#: 101466 | EMPLOYEE NAME: ANGELINA CASIANO'

select substring(@val, charindex('CUSTOMER NAME:', @val) + 15, charindex('INVOICE DATE:', @val) - (charindex('CUSTOMER NAME:', @val) + 18))
```

Comment: this is the error:  Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Comment: Does all your strings have the same format as the string stored in the @val variable?

Comment: No they keep changing depending on the length of the name

Comment: That is understandable. But what I meant is whether there is any difference in the overall structure of strings..

Comment: @Looking_for_answers what is meant is: is "CUSTOMER NAME" always immediately followed by "INVOICE DATE", like in this sample, or can the fragments be in any order?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that looks for `CUSTOMER NAME`:

```
with params as (
      select ' CUSTOMER NAME: ' as custname
     )
select t.*,
       (case when t.col like '%' + custname + '%'
             then s2.s2 
        end) as customer_name
from params cross join
     t outer apply
     (select substring(t.col, charindex(custname, col + custname), len(col))as s1
     ) s1 outer apply
     (select stuff(left(s1.s1, charindex('|', s1.s1 + '|') - 2),
                   1, len(custname) + 1, ''
                  ) as s2
     ) s2;
```

This should work if `customer_name` is at the end of the string, regardless of the order of the values, and even if `'CUSTOMER NAME'` is not in the string at all.

Of course, if you are using SQL Server 2016, then a solution using `split_string()` is better.